# Switching between windows of an app in different spaces shortcut?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion, osx-spaces

If there are two different instances/windows of the same application located in two spaces, each window inside another space. What is the easiest way (preferably with a keyboard shortcut) to move/navigate/switch between them?

Right now I can click on the app icon in the dock multiple times to navigate to a different window, but it is becoming tedious.

Comment: You're trying to fight a paradigm. Spaces does not cope well at all if an app is on multiple Spaces. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193937/shortcut-for-toggling-between-different-windows-of-same-app/193938#193938 for an unsatisfactory workaround. The 'easiest' way, so long as you don't use fullscreen, is to switch to a numbered Space by its shortcut - not try to pull the app to the font, pull the Space.

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you, this is a good idea, I will arrange them in subsequent spaces and use shortcuts to switch to the desired space.